# How to get fetchSize value set from stmt.fetchSize(500) in DSI in simba jdbc sdk

Tags: jdbc, simba

I am using SIMBA SDK 9.5 trail version for creating a custom JDBC4.1 driver to access my data store hive. For testing simba jdbc driver, I have a java class.

Below is my sample code:

```java
Class.forName("com.simba.ultralight.core.jdbc41.ULJDBC41Driver");
Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:simba://localhost", "root",""); 
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setFetchSize(500);
```

As from my java application, I am setting fetchSize of 500. How do I get the value of fetch size in my custom implementation class i.e  custom DSI implemented. I have ULStatement extends DSIStatement and ULPersonTable extends DSISimpleResultSet in my code. I want to get this fetch size value in my DSI code, as  I will be using this fetch size in my DSI class to fetch specified number of data from our data store.

Comment: [`Statement.getFetchSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getFetchSize--)?

Comment: Note that the fetch size doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. The fetch size is **not** the total number of rows to fetch (that is `maxRows`), it is an optimization hint to the driver to fetch rows in batches of `fetchSize` (the driver is free to ignore it).

Comment: I have created custom driver, using SIMBA SDK, So I want to know which DSI method will return me the the fetch size. Statement.getFetchSize won't work in SIMBA SDK Case

Comment: Hi Reena, were you able to find help yourself, or is this question still outstanding? I work for Simba and would be happy to help, or you can email us at Simba for direct help.

Comment: Hi  KylePorter, Thanks for your response. I want not able to get the answer to this question.